# How do you hide a div element based on user input on a Razor Page?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a country field and a state field. I want to show the state field when the user chooses United States. Otherwise, I want it to be hidden.

This is my cshtml page of the form.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.Country" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.Country" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>Mexico</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.State" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.State" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-select">
        <option disabled selected>Choose your State</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.State" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.City" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Form.City" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.City" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I tried searching for a solution, but most involve using JS which I don't know and don't want to use now.

I know razor is server side code, but maybe I can integrate a blazor component or use css to achieve this.

Comment: If you don't wanna use javascript, I think you need to integrate Razor components into razor pages and write code in .razor file, But i think it is too complicated, I still recommend you to use js.

Comment: @XinranShen you're right,. I will try using js for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very glad to see you can receive to use javascript to do it, Here is a simple demo with annotations, I hope it can solve your issue.

add a `onchange()` method on the first dropdown list:

```
<select asp-for="Form.Country" class="form-control" onchange="Select()">
```

add an Id for the second dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4" id="demo">
    .........
</div>
```

Then write a javascript in your view:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function Select(){
            //get the element by id
            var select = document.getElementById("Form_Country");
            //get the option's text
            var index = select.selectedIndex;
            var text = select.options[index].text;
            //if option's text is not United States, hide the second dropdownlist.
            if(text!="United States"){
                //hiden the dropdownlist
                document.getElementById("demo").style.display='none';
            }else{
                //show the dropdownlist
                document.getElementById("demo").style.display='block';
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Demo:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
@if (Form.Country == "UnitedStates")
{
 MARKUP FOR STATE DROPDOWN
}
```